# How can I make pybluez return a list of discovered devices every X seconds and then repeat?

Tags: python, bluetooth

I've been trying to figure out how I can use [pybluez](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/) to monitor nearby devices...

I want to be able to run my program and have it search for devices every 20 seconds. The problem is, how do I get pybluez to place nicely? :/

Using their example code http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/inquiry.py, it's easy enough to get it to discover devices. You run that code and it'll spit out MAC address and, if you choose, the device names.

How can I put this in a loop? I've been playing around with the following code but it's failing >.<

```
import bluetooth

def search():
   while True:
      devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True)

      yield devices

for addr, name in search():
   print "{0} - {1}".format(addr, name)
```

Answer (score 7):

This code worked for me:

```
'''
Created on Nov 16, 2011    
@author: Radu
'''
import time
import bluetooth

def search():         
    devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=20, lookup_names = True)
    return devices

if __name__=="__main__":
    while True:        
        results = search()
        if (results!=None):
            for addr, name in results:
                print "{0} - {1}".format(addr, name)
            #endfor
        #endif
        time.sleep(60)
    #endwhile
```

It searches for 20 seconds for a device, and then sleeps for 1 minute, all in an infinite loop. I am working on Windows, with default windows drivers on a Serioux BT Dongle.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know pybluez, but `bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True)` itself already returns an iterable, so you should loop it for yielding.

```
def search():
   while True:
      devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True)
      for x in devices: # <--
         yield x        # <--
```

Comment: This works great but...
Looks like the devices are cached?
I would like to get a notification if a bluetooth device is not around but, even if I turn it off, it still appears in scanning...

Comment: Lol this is barely belivable.
I got here thinking "Amazing, this is the same problem I have!" it was me two years ago :'(

Comment: @Pitto https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/23d34718046b2ad40bd519bea26cac38d33933a7/bluetooth/msbt.py